# Fastest way of getting intervals from a boolian vector in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a boolian vector

```
v=[True,True,True,False,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,True]
```

I want to get the intervals that contain the `True` values.

```
#intervals in the format: [start,stop]
[[0,2],
 [4,5],
 [8,9],
 [11,11]]
```

Is there any commonly used function in python (let's say in `numpy`) that can do this.

Comment: Your indices are even similar to the duplicate. I wonder if it's something about what we consider to be random grouping.

Comment: Thats coincidental. I looked around first if anybody had asked this question. I did not find that (duplicate) one. Anyway the difference in my question is that I want to know thd fastest way.

Comment: My recommendation would be to take the answer here and benchmark it against the ones in the other question.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the fastest but probably one of the shortest. The new `prepend` and `append` keywords to `np.diff` are very convenient for this kind of task.

```
np.flatnonzero(np.diff(v, prepend=False, append=False)).reshape(-1, 2) - (0, 1)
```